managed identity set on azure container app job with AcrPush fails authentication to pull image
I've been using deployment stacks to deploy container apps with bicep.  Something like this:
az stack group create --name ${GEN_APPNAME}-${GEN_ENVIRO}-deploy-stack \
    --resource-group ${GEN_RESOURCE_GROUP} \
    --template-file ${FILE} \
    --parameters ${PFILE} \
    --deny-settings-mode 'none' \
    --verbose

My bicep file looks like this:
resource uai 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-07-31-preview' existing = {
  name: miName
}
...
resource containerApp 'Microsoft.App/jobs@2023-11-02-preview' = {
  name: containerAppName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${uai.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    environmentId: containerAppEnv.id
    configuration: {
      replicaTimeout: 43200
      triggerType: 'Manual'

      registries: [
        {
          server: containerRegistryName
          identity: uai.id
        }
      ]
    }
...

the managed identity has AcrPush (which includes pull)
When I run the command I get the following error:
Code: InvalidParameterValueInContainerTemplate Message: The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Field 'template.containers.llexport.image' is invalid with details: 'Invalid value: "xxxx.azurecr.io/llexport:7cfedd7": GET https:?scope=repository%3Allexport%3Apull&service=xxxx.azurecr.io: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.';.
So the strange thing is this setup worked previously, and still works with container apps that aren't jobs.
I deployed ms hello world this way
I have hardcoded the actual id in the bicep file
Validated the managed id exists and has AcrPull
Manually created another mid with contributor and tried that one
validated ARM audience tokens for authentication is enabled on registry
I can deploy that container and version using the following command:
az containerapp job create --name llexport \
    --resource-group rg-xxx-uat \
    --environment acaenv-xxx-xxx-uat \
    --image xxx.azurecr.io/llexport:$HASH \
    --registry-server xxx.azurecr.io \
    --query properties.template \
    --output yaml > llexport-config-output.yml \
    --registry-identity id-xxx-uat \
    --trigger-type "Manual" \
    --replica-timeout 300 \
    --replica-retry-limit 1 \
    --parallelism 1 \
    --replica-completion-count 1 \

EDITS:
az command works as expected when I use --registry-identity instead of --identity
Validated ARM audience tokens enabled
Has something changed in jobs that this now shouldn't work?

It looks like you are trying to use a user-assigned managed identity to pull images from a private Azure Container Registry repository, but you are getting an authentication error. One thing to check is if your Azure Container Registry allows ARM audience tokens for authentication. You can check this using the following command: az acr config authentication-as-arm show -r . If ARM tokens are disallowed, you can allow them with the following command: az acr config authentication-as-arm update -r  --status enabled. output

Additionally, it seems that the container app job is not using the identity you give it, but instead using your credentials to get the password. This could be because the identity is not properly configured or assigned the correct roles. I would recommend checking that the user-assigned managed identity has the acrpull role assigned to it for the Azure Container Registry.

I saw the ARM token check yesterday and I did do that and it was enabled, good suggestion.  I have validated the identity has the correct permissions.  if I deploy a container app (not job) this all works with the same identity

what about jobs? btw I have shared docs on both container app and job using managed identity in my below answer under reference section.

yes, I checked jobs too

It seems that the container app job is not using the identity you gave it, your command is not using the managed identity to authenticate with azure container registry to get the image. Would request you to first login with your managed identity as below-
az login --identity

followed by
az login --identity --username <client_id|object_id|resource_id>


refer this doc
Once successfully logged in, now run your command-
az containerapp job create --name llexport \
    --resource-group rg-xxx-uat \
    --environment acaenv-xxx-xxx-uat \
    --image xxx.azurecr.io/llexport:$HASH \
    --registry-server xxx.azurecr.io \
    --query properties.template \
    --output yaml > llexport-config-output.yml \
    --mi-user-assigned id-xxx-uat \
    --trigger-type "Manual" \
    --replica-timeout 300 \
    --replica-retry-limit 1 \
    --parallelism 1 \
    --replica-completion-count 1 \


jobs will get triggered.

Note, --mi-system-assigned parameter is not for the authentication it is only for assigning the identity to the job. please refer this doc
Below are few additional checks I would recommend you to check-
if your Azure Container Registry allows ARM audience tokens for authentication. You can check this using the following command:  az acr config authentication-as-arm show -r <REGISTRY>. If ARM tokens are disallowed, you can allow them with the following command:  az acr config authentication-as-arm update -r <REGISTRY> --status enabled.

then check if the identity is not properly configured or assigned the correct roles.


References:

Azure Container Apps image pull with managed identity (command-line)
Azure Container Apps image pull with managed identity (azure-portal)
az containerapp job
Sign in with a managed identity using Azure CLI


thanks for the proposal, however the problem I'm having specifically is when I try to create it with deployment stack and bicep.  Setting the registry identity works for regular apps but not for jobs.  However it used to work.
